# What would be the best way to save and retrieve an array of string in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

I need to save the last 10 paths (strings) of files found in a directory. What would be the best way to easily save and retrieve them?

I was thinking about reading and writing to a txt file but I was wondering if there was an easier more efficient way to do that in WPF.

Comment: I edit my post.please see again.

Comment: Do you need i make you a pictural tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use settings to save your data.
do double click on settings and choose the type -> Browse -> system -> System.Collection.Specialized -> StringCollection . 
and choose Scope as User.

just note that first time to use this collection you should create instance of it with new key word.
I know it is not easier. but i am sure it is cleaner.

to do this, first add this namespace:

```
       using MyWpfApplication.Properties;
```

then use it in this way:

```
       if (Settings.Default.MyStringCollection== null)
        {
            Settings.Default.MyStringCollection= new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
            Settings.Default.MyStringCollection.Add("string1");
            Settings.Default.MyStringCollection.Add("string2");

            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = Settings.Default.MyStringCollection;
        }
```

Comment: I was under the impression the we couldn’t save arrays in user settings.

Comment: Yes it is interesting. We can do it

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial that shows how to save an array in user setting?

Comment: what is your mean? I show it to you. it is very simple.

Comment: But how do you retrieve the info once it is saved?

Comment: Using settings for things unrelated to settings does not look like the best option.

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani - Quick question, just to be clear on the example you posted, is that user settings? Sorry about the silly question but I have never use user settings.

Comment: Yes that is user setting

Comment: Your welcome. if you need more help, please let me help you

Comment: FYI - @ SaeedBolhasani - I think your code it's missing `Properties` as follow... `Properties.Settings.Default.MyStringCollection`. By the way, using UserSettings it's very easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Serializer to write the array to any kind of file: Json, xml, binary, anything. Then, when you need to load the array, you just Deserialize the file and you have your array variable again.

See this article on how serialization works for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/

Comment: Interesting, I’ll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Configuration file[Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.100).aspx) file.
[ConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

I don't think it will support array.  You would need path01 - path10.

If you want more of a List then use XML.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little more on the XML way or point me to where I can find more info?